# Android - location not updating

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps, location, google-api-client

At the moment when i use the geo fix lng lat command my application doesn't pick up that the location has changed. My simplified code looks like this:

```
if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    Location lastKnownLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

        if (lastKnownLocation!= null){
            Log.d("Log", "Lat: " + lastKnownLocation.getLatitude());
            Log.d("Log", "Lng: " + lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
        } else {
            Log.d("Log", "No location detected");
        }
}
```

googleApiClient:

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
```

So with the activity containing that code running i can send the command "geo fix 10 10" and reload that code (via a refresh button) but it will still log 
    "No location Detected"

However, if I open the Google maps application within the emulator and then go back to my application and hit refresh again it will output:
    "Lat: 10"
    "lng: 10"

It appears that opening the map application is triggering some sort of update of the apps location that geo fix doesn't?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after doing a bit of digging through the docs and other questions on here I found that I wasn't actually updating the location at all within the app. (Which was what Google Maps did when I opened it and hence triggered the new location to be set)

It now works (when the app is in the foreground) with this implementation:

```
protected GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
protected LocationRequest locationRequest;

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

And then within the overridden onConnected method:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,locationRequest, this);
}
```

Plus the onLocationChanged method is required as the class is now implementing LocationListener

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //Whatever is required when the location changes
}
```